# In XML, how do you ignore dangling text that is not surrounded by tags?

Tags: c#, xml, file-io, io, xmlwriter

I am encountering this issue where the xml file that I am reading may have dangling text (I do not know what it is called for those text that is not surrounded by any tags).

For example :

```
<Book>
    <Title>The Catcher in the Rye</Title>
    <Author>Salinger</Author>
</Book>
Useless jiberish
<Book>
    <Title>Jaws</Title>
    <Author>Benchley</Author>
</Book>
```

It is perfect xml except for the line "Useless jiberish". Reading occurs without any problem, however writing using streamwriter with

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.NewLineOnAttributes = true;
settings.Indent = true;
```

It writes perfectly until the line with "Useless jiberish"

```
<Book>
    <Title>The Catcher in the Rye</Title>
    <Author>Salinger</Author>
</Book>Useless jiberish<Book><Title>Jaws</Title><Author>Bencheley</Author>
```

If I delete the "Useless jiberish" from the xml document it works perfectly. However I do not have that option. Is there any suggestion/clue as to why this is occuring? It may be really simple thing that I am missing.

Any suggestions help.

Thank you.

Comment: are you reading or writing that xml

Comment: I am doing both. From what I look at the reading is processed properly. However when I write it back using MemoryStream it is not writing back properly.

Comment: show us the code you are using to write the xml

Answer (score 0):

You might look into using the XDocument class from System.Xml.Linq.  Loading the file would look something like:

```
        string file = @"c:\test\movies.xml";
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(file);
        foreach (XElement e in doc.Root.Descendants())
        {

        }
```

More info can be found about XDocument [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx).